# Worklight - jquery mobile | How to check if a user is logged in in pagebeforeshow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to check if a user is set (global variable is not undefined/null) before every page is loaded in jquery mobile.

What is the best way to do this?

I thought to do this

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#mainPage", function(){
if(window.klappr.userId === undefined || window.klappr.userId == null){
                  $.mobile.changePage($("#loginPage"));
        }else{
loadMainOverview();
         }
});
```

But how to stop the first changePage? (to main)
Isn't there a better way to check this for all the protected pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pagebeforechange`, as it will prevent showing the target page. Using `pagebeforeshow` will result in showing the target page and then jump to #loginpage.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function(e) {
  if(window.klappr.userId === undefined || window.klappr.userId == null) {
    $.mobile.changePage($("#loginPage"));
    e.preventDefault();
  } 
  else {
    loadMainOverview();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile provide local storage store data in local storage, you can use as globally.

```
 localStorage.setItem("userId", value);
 localStorage.getItem(userId);

 $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#mainPage", function(){
 if(localStorage.getItem(userId) === undefined || localStorage.getItem(userId) == null){
              $.mobile.changePage($("#loginPage"));
    }else{
 loadMainOverview();
     }
 });
```